# getUserMedia constraint: highest resolution up to a limit

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, resolution, getusermedia

I'm accessing the webcam with this code:

```
getUserMedia( { 'video': true }, success, failure );
```

Now I'd like to get the highest resolution possible, up to a limit of 720 vertical pixels, so I change it to this:

```
getUserMedia( { 'video': {
    'optional': [
        { 'height': { 'max': 720 } },
        { 'maxHeight': 720 }
    ]
} }, success, failure );
```

But it does nothing. I still get a video which is 480 pixels high.

Weirdly, if I change it to use `min` instead of `max`, it sort-of works in Chrome (it chooses the highest resolution available, with no limit). Adding a `max` makes it fail again. None of these seem to work in FireFox.

I realise constraints are still not really standard, but is there any way with the current state of things to reliably do this?

Update: turns out [FireFox only supports 640x480](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Media/getUserMedia#Status), so this question will have to be Chrome-only for now.

Comment: Probably because max resolution is the maximum resolution you want while min res is the minimum you want.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson well, yes, so setting a max of 720 would, logically, choose 720 if it's possible, but never allow anything higher. But it seems it doesn't, or at least didn't when I was testing this. I haven't tested lately but I think this may have been fixed in a more recent release of Chrome.

Comment: I think it could chose nothing that was larger than 720px. That what max means it says nothing about the lower bound. Just how large it can maximally be.

Comment: I found this link http://webrtchacks.com/how-to-figure-out-webrtc-camera-resolutions/ explains a bit more.

Comment: **Update:** Firefox is ahead of Chrome here now, and supports the spec, so this is a piece of cake: `{ video: { width: 9999, height: 9999 } }` will give you the highest possible resolution. See [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282385/webrtc-firefox-constraints/28911694#28911694).