# WebRTC firefox constraints

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

I currently use WebRTC in my personal development, everything works fine. I get the stream from my webcam, but now I want to use constraints for `getUserMedia()`.

```
var constraints = {
           audio: false,
           video: {
               mandatory : {
                     minWidth: 1280,
                     minHeight: 720 
               }
           }
};
```

When I test this in Firefox it seems to ignore the constraints. When I test on Chrome or Opera my constraints work fine and my quality is good, anyone know why? The problem is Firefox?

Thanks for you suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [getUserMedia() video size in Firefox & Chrome differs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415778/getusermedia-video-size-in-firefox-chrome-differs)

Comment: Yes I have see your link, but I I haven't found solution for my problem, I can't change the video quality in firefox but I don't understand why my code work fine in chrome, maybe a codec video I don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Edit** the wiki link seems to be outdated, please refer to [jib's answer down below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28911694/980524)

It seems like [Firefox has not yet implemented constraints.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

> Constraints have been implemented since Chrome 24 and Opera 18. These can be used to set values for video resolution for getUserMedia() and RTCPeerConnection addStream() calls.

and from: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Media/getUserMedia

> Capture resolution [in Firefox] currently fixed to 640x480 for video;

It only supports

> Minimal constraints supported: (Note: all of these booleans default to 'false')
>     video:   true/false
>     audio:   true/false
>     fake:    true/false
>     picture: true/false

Comment: That wiki is outdated. Firefox *does* support constraints. See my answer.

Comment: also to be noticed for older ff version *(don't quite know which one + I noticed it varied a lot between mac&linux and win versions)* their was an option in about:config to set those constraints manually, see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17529034/3702797

Answer (score 33):

Firefox [***does*** support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Parameters) a subset of constraints with `getUserMedia()`, but not the outdated syntax that Chrome and Opera are using. The `mandatory` / `optional` syntax was deprecated years ago, and `minWidth` and `minHeight` the year before that.

### The MediaCapture specification

[According to the specification](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#constrainable-interface), which is now stable, your example should be written like this:

```
var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        width: { min: 1280 },
        height: { min: 720 },
    }
};
```

This works in Firefox (and Chrome with adapter.js): https://jsfiddle.net/34qxx5w1

In the specification, the keywords `min`, `max`, and `exact` (a.k.a. min == max) are inherently mandatory, whereas plain values and `ideal` are not. Here's a fuller example:

```
var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        width: { min: 1024, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
        height: { min: 576, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
    }
};
```

This works in Firefox (and Chrome with the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill in straightforward cases).

An `ideal` value, when used, has gravity, which means that the browser will try to find the setting (and camera, if you have more than one), with the smallest [fitness distance](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dfn-fitness-distance) from the ideal values given.

Plain values are inherently ideal, which means that:

```
var constraints = { video: { width: 640, height: 480 } };
```

is the same as:

```
var constraints = { video: { width: { ideal: 640 }, height: { ideal: 480 } } };
```

In other words, a preference that `getUserMedia()` will try to honor, but never fail over.

If you **must** have a specific resolution, use this shorthand:

```
var constraints = { video: { width: { exact: 640 }, height: { exact: 480 } } };
```

### Firefox

As of right now, `width`, `height`, `frameRate` and (on mobile) `facingMode` are supported in Firefox. Also, some caveats by version:

- **FF32-37:** Plain values and `ideal` are not supported. However, values are not mandatory unless you add a non-spec [`require`](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/34qxx5w1/13) keyword.
- **FF38+:** Implements the spec for the above constraints. Improved handling of Mac cameras (though frameRate has limitations on Mac).
- **FF43+:** Implements `MediaStreamTrack.applyConstraints()` and `mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()`.
- **FF46+:** Implements `echoCancellation`.

Comment: **Update:** [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) now lets you use spec-constraints with both Chrome and Firefox!

Comment: **Update:** All the browsers support spec-constraints by now.