# Display html video using getusermedia

Tags: javascript, video, innerhtml, webcam, getusermedia

I wish to display html video using the getusermedia (captured using webcam) after user click the button. The video tag will be display using innerhtml.

When user click the button the video is displayed but it does not capture the webcam.

```
<button id="rec" onclick="onBtnRecordClicked()">Record</button>
<button id="stop"  onclick="onBtnStopClicked()" disabled>Stop</button>

 <div id="videos-container"></div>

<script>
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    document.getElementById('rec').onclick = function() {
    var htmlElement = document.createElement('video');
    htmlElement.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
    htmlElement.setAttribute('controls', true);
    videosContainer.insertBefore(htmlElement, videosContainer.firstChild);

    var mediaConfig = {
            video: htmlElement,
            onsuccess: function(stream) {
                src: URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            },
            onerror: function() {
                alert('unable to get access to your webcam');
            }
        };
        getUserMedia(mediaConfig);
    }

var videosContainer = document.getElementById('videos-container') || document.body;

</script>
```

i am getting getUserMedia not defined in console.

code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/590c2mcp/

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/srn9db4h/

Comment: @jib the code doesn't work on chrome? i test in chrome but there no video. it work on firefox.. but my site features work mostly in chrome..

Comment: Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/k8rened5/) that should work in Chrome (which doesn't support `srcObject` yet). Note that this still requires either the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill or enabling *chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features* in Chrome. Or you can use the deprecated non-promise api [`navigator.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia).

Answer (score 2):

To make getUserMedia work in all browsers, including Chrome, you have a two options:

1. **Best option:** Use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter), the official WebRTC polyfill, until Chrome [unprefs the latest APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility). ([https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srn9db4h/) for Chrome):

   ```js
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video:true, audio:true })
     .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
     .catch(log);

   var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
   <video id="video" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
   <div id="div"></div>
   ```

   It shims both `navigator.mediaDevices` and `srcObject`.
2. Use the deprecated API for a while longer ([https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vnn0dyw/) for Chrome):

   ```js
   navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;

   new Promise((y, n) => navigator.getUserMedia({ video:true, audio:true }, y, n))
     .then(stream => video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream))
     .catch(log);

   var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
   ```

   ```html
   <video id="video" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
   <div id="div"></div>
   ```

   Though this may not work in MS Edge.

I'm not recommending the second option, more including it for historical context, as there's still a lot of code floating out there that looks more or less like it (minus the promise wrapper). Once you start using [constraints, you'll notice those have changed too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28911694/918910), so stick with [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter).

Comment: What would we need to do to get this work without adapter https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js

Comment: @Ankit this is an old answer. You don't need adapter.js for this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 this works for me:

consider that you have a video element:

```
<video id="my-video"></video>
```

then you can show video from the webcam using:

```
const constraints = { video: { width:1280, height:720 } };
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video#my-video');
videoElement.srcObject = stream;
```

but remember to catch errors from `getUserMedia` call, it will throw error if the device is not available. E.g. this happens if a laptop is not open (e.g. using external monitor, but no external webcam).

Answer (score -1):

There is no `getUserMedia` in the global scope, you need to use the `getUserMedia` method from `mediaDevices`

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConfig);
```

Comment: i am still getting getUserMedia not defined after imputing yr code.

Answer (score -1):

After chrome 74, getUserMedia is only available in the HTTPS context. However, you can disable that in the experimental features here: `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`