# WebCam - Browser does not support getUserMedia in IE Edge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webcam, getusermedia, webcam.js

I am developing an Angular application that needs photo capturing functionality. For that purpose, I am using WebCam directive by referring following links.

https://github.com/jonashartmann/webcam-directive

https://jonas.hartmann.site/webcam-directive/#/

After developing whole page, I am now stuck unit testing on Edge due to 'Browser does not support getUserMedia' error. After googling for solution, I came across links that says, Edge doesn't have support for getUserMedia.

[how to make getUserMedia() work on all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015847/how-to-make-getusermedia-work-on-all-browsers)

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/accessing-the-device-camera-with-getusermedia

I think, there will be alternate solution for this scenario but I can't figure it out.

NOTE: webcam.min.js file already used

```
navigator.getMedia=navigator.getUserMedia||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia||navigator.mozGetUserMedia||navigator.msGetUserMedia
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`It is supported on Edge, version 14+`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream),  [`IE Solution`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt131861(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Wfm in Edge 40.15063. As a side-note there are [newer APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37366638/918910) you should use.

Comment: Webcam.js has a fallback if `getUserMedia` is not supported. It should be able to fall back to Flash.