# Change HTML5 video element aspect ratio on Firefox and Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, video, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm trying to create a HTML5 video element that streams from the local camera with the exact size of 380 x 214 pixels. I found that the only way to do this is using `mandatory` with `minWidth`, `minHeight` etc.

So this code works great on **chrome**, but **not on Firefox or Microsoft Edge**.

```
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                             navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                             navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    navigator.getUserMedia(
    {
        audio: true,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                minWidth: 380,
                minHeight: 214,
                maxWidth: 380,
                maxHeight: 214
            }
        }
    }, function (stream) {
       ....
    });
```

I've been attempting various properties to the `video` element, but none of them seem to change its default 4:3 aspect ratio on those browsers.

[image]

Any idea how can I resolve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC firefox constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282385/webrtc-firefox-constraints)